# UIImageJPEGRepresentation doen't keep my scale settings

Tags: ios, uiimage, nsdata

When I use initWithCGImage with a certain scale and then UIImageJPEGRepresentation to get data from this image, it seems the system doesn't keep my scale settings. Any idea why ?

Following is my code and the log I get :

```
ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
CGImageRef iref = [rep fullResolutionImage];
UIImageOrientation orientation = [self orientationForAsset:asset];

// Scale the image                          
UIImage* scaledImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:iref scale:2. orientation:orientation];
NSLog (@"Scaled image size %@", NSStringFromCGSize(scaledImage.size));

// Get data from image
NSData* scaledImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(scaledImage, 0.8);

//  Check the image size of the data
UIImage* buildedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:scaledImageData];
NSLog (@"Data image size of %@", NSStringFromCGSize (buildedImage.size));
```

Gives log :

"Scaled image size {1944, 1296}"

"Data image size of {3888, 2592}"

That's really strange because the two images are supposed to be exactly the same.

Comment: IMHO jpeg knows nothing about scale

Comment: The thing is that if I upload the scaledImageData, on the server I get an image that has the original size and not the scaled one.

Comment: If you gave values closer to 1 for `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` it will reduce the quality of the image. So make it smaller like `0.2`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ***-[UIImage imageWithData:scale:]*** method.

Comment: My problem is that when I upload the scaledImageData, the server gets the image with the original size and not the scaled one. The buildedImage in my code was just to check what was really in  my NSData before uploading.

Comment: Then @sage444's comment on your question is the answer for your question.

Comment: I guess so... This mean I'll need to create an image with the original scale. Then build another image with the dimension I need and send the data from this second image.

Comment: But I guess you need to have a param to send the 'scale' to the server. So you can use it to convert data back to image.